# Proc sql add column to order winners

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I need your help , I have an exercise which ask to order winners by the total of medal , if the number of medals are the same for two country then i need to compare for 3 column by order (which are types of medals) .

so i have

```
sum(3columns) as total
order total desc, col1 desc , col2 desc , col3 desc
```

then i saved it as table , and added monotonic() as winner's place (1 2 3 4 ...)
but i got 3 team which have the same total result and same value in the 3 columns
so they must be place 25 all of them, but i'm struggling to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `monotonic()` is not a supported function and can be tricky in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data correctly and then use FIRST/LAST/BY group processing.

```
proc sort data = have;
    by descending Total_Medals descending Gold descending Silver descending Bronze;
run;

data want; 
 set have;

 by descending Total_Medals descending Gold descending Silver descending Bronze;

 Rank = _n_;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `first.` evaluation of the the last variable in the `by` group to determine when to increment an overall rank value.

```
* sample data;
data have (keep=eventid teamid medal);
  length eventid teamid 8 medal $8;
  do eventid = 1 to 75;
    g = ceil(100 * ranuni(123));
    do until (s ne g);
      s = ceil(100 * ranuni(123));
    end;
    do until (b ne g and b ne s);
      b = ceil(100 * ranuni(123));
    end;

    teamid = g; medal = 'gold'; output;
    teamid = s; medal = 'silver'; output;
    teamid = b; medal = 'bronze'; output;
  end;
run;

* compute medal count for each team;    
proc summary noprint data=have ;
  class teamid medal;
  ways 2;
  output out=stage2(drop=_type_);
run;

* pivot categorical medal counts into wide form;
proc transpose data=stage2 out=stage3(drop=_name_);
  by teamid;
  var _freq_;
  id medal;
run;

* compute each medaling teams total medal count;
data stage4;
  retain teamid total gold silver bronze; * sets order of variables in pdv;
  set stage3;
  total = sum (gold, silver, bronze);
run;

* sort descendingly by total and medal quality in preparation of rank assignment;
proc sort data=stage4;
  by descending total descending gold descending silver descending bronze;
run;

* assign dense rank;
data want;
  set stage4;
  by descending total descending gold descending silver descending bronze;

  if first.bronze then /* new combination detected */
    overall_rank + 1;
run;
```